# How to handle white spaces in dataframe column names in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I registered a tmp table from a df that has white spaces in the column header.how can i extract the column while using sql query via sqlContext.
I tried to use back-tick but it is not working

```
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select Company, Sector, Industry, `Altman Z-score as Z_Score` from tmp1 """)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to place only the column name within back-ticks, not its alias:

**Without Alias**:

```
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select Company, Sector, Industry, `Altman Z-score` as Z_Score from tmp1""")
```

**With Alias**:

```
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select t1.Company, t1.Sector, t1.Industry, t1.`Altman Z-score` as Z_Score from tmp1 t1""")
```

Comment: seems as it does not work with alias.

df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select t1.Company, t1.Sector, t1.Industry, `t1.Altman Z-score` as Z_Score from tmp1 t1""")

Comment: By alias I meant new name for `Altman Z-score` column, which is `Z_Score`, not the `tmp1 t1`. Have you tried what is provided in answer ?

Comment: Yes the answer works. but not with the alias name `t1.Altman Z-score` as Z_Score

Comment: If you want it to work with alias name then also you have to put only column name in back-ticks, not the alias. I have updated my answer for it.

Answer (score 5):

There is problem in query, Corrected query is below (**wrapped as Z_Score in ``**) :-

```
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select Company, Sector, Industry, `Altman Z-score` as Z_Score from tmp1 """)
```

One more Alternate:-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select * from tmp1 """)
df1.select(F.col("Altman Z-score").alias("Z_Score")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-spaces-in-mysql

Please refer the above link to use the ` symbol a toggle key for Tilda ~ to refer a column with spaces. I have tried the below code and it has worked

```
data = spark.read.options(header='True',inferschema='True',delimiter=',').csv(r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\diabetes.csv')
data.createOrReplaceTempView("DIABETICDATA")
spark.sql("""SELECT `Number of times pregnant` FROM DIABETICDATA WHERE `Number of times pregnant` > 10 """).show()
```