# PySpark how to rename column with error-producing name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to query a DF in PySpark that contains an improperly named column. I cannot change this name outside of PySpark since it's buried within 1TB of JSON.

Here's the code I'm using to change the name:

```
data.select('fields').withColumn('npa_case_id ID', 'npa_case_id_ID').show()
```

The column name is `npa_case_id ID` and PySpark is complaining about the space. The above code doesn't work, however, and produces the following error:

```
An error was encountered:
"cannot resolve '`npa_case_id ID`' given input columns: [fields];;\n'Project ['npa_case_id ID]\n+- Project [fields#12]\n   +- Relation[_id#6,blexts#7,bookmarked#8,bookmarks#9,centroid#10,context#11,fields#12,geometry#13,has_premium#14,key#15,metadata#16,others#17,path#18,premium_field_metadata#19,reference_links#20,sources#21,spec#22,status#23] json\n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1327, in select
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`npa_case_id ID`' given input columns: [fields];;\n'Project ['npa_case_id ID]\n+- Project [fields#12]\n   +- Relation[_id#6,blexts#7,bookmarked#8,bookmarks#9,centroid#10,context#11,fields#12,geometry#13,has_premium#14,key#15,metadata#16,others#17,path#18,premium_field_metadata#19,reference_links#20,sources#21,spec#22,status#23] json\n"
```

How can I solve the Catch-22 of changing the name of a column that produces an error. Alternatively, I'm happy to drop the column altogether if that's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle white spaces in dataframe column names in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108007/how-to-handle-white-spaces-in-dataframe-column-names-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

which version of spark you are using?
I am using 2.4 and able to create new col with space

```
>>> df.show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|   A|
|  2|   B|
+---+----+

# withColumn
>>> df.withColumn('new name', df.name).show()
+---+----+--------+
| id|name|new name|
+---+----+--------+
|  1|   A|       A|
|  2|   B|       B|
+---+----+--------+

# withColumnRenamed
>>> df.withColumnRenamed('name', 'new name').show()
+---+--------+
| id|new name|
+---+--------+
|  1|       A|
|  2|       B|
+---+--------+
```